# Avoid repeated values on SQL query, reservations application

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

first time I ask a question here, I'm coding a reservations application on C# using Visual Studio 2015, but I have a problem trying to show free rooms on a data grid view, here is the query i'm using:

```
SELECT clientID, cost, arrival, roomNumber, resvNum, departure, size
FROM roomswithresvView
WHERE (roomNumber NOT IN
       (SELECT  roomNumber
          FROM    roomswithresvView AS roomswithresvView_1
           WHERE   (arrival BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2) 
             OR (departure BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2)))
```

The problem is that if a room has more than one reservation, the query will show it multiple times, I have tried using DISTINCT but I can only make work with one column and I haven't been able to make GROUP BY work.

Thanks for your attention.

[Query Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVqm4.jpg)

For example, if I test the query with 2016-07-06 as date1 and 2016-07-07 as date2, it will repeat room 1005 because it has two reservations on the database.

Comment: But you are asking for the reservations.  You should delete this question and ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: can you mention which column is distinct ?

Comment: Thank you, i have been testing it on roomNumber, that's where I can see when a room repeats

Comment: so in your table room number is not unique already ...sorry i think you need to post a sample output so that people can understand what exactly you need

Answer (score 0):

Where were you putting the DISTINCT?

You need a table for rooms, and a table for reservations. Then you need a subquery to find reservations that clash with your requested dates. This is where you use DISTINCT. Then you need an outer query to find all rooms not returned in the subquery. Don't forget the case where you have an existing reservation that starts before and ends after your requested dates! Putting that all together, you get this...

```
 insert into room(costPerNight, roomNumber, size)
 values
 (55, 1, 13),
 (65, 2, 15),
 (85, 3, 20)
 ;

 create table reservation(
 id int identity (1,1) not null,
 roomId int not null,
 dateIn date not null,
 dateOut date not null
 )

 insert into reservation (roomId, dateIn, dateOut)
 values
 (1,'2016-07-01','2016-07-03'),
 (1,'2016-07-05','2016-07-08'),
 (2,'2016-07-01','2016-07-08')
 */

 declare @requestedDateIn date = '2016-07-03'
 declare @requestedDateOut date = '2016-07-05';

 select * from room where id not in(
 --find clashing reservations
 select distinct roomId from reservation where 
 (dateOut > @requestedDateIn and dateOut < @requestedDateOut)
 or (dateIn > @requestedDateIn and dateIn < @requestedDateOut)
 or (dateIn < @requestedDateIn and dateOut > @requestedDateOut)
 )
```